# Qt stylesheet and QString::arg()

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qstring

To keep a Stylesheet dynamic regarding DPI settings, I want to set certain parts of it from code.

This works:

```
my_label->setStyleSheet( QString( "font-size: 30px;" ) );
```

Yet, this doesn't:

```
my_label->setStyleSheet( QString( "font-size: %1px;" ).arg( 30 ) );
```

Can anyone enlighten me, why this is? Running Qt 5.7.

Comment: What do you get from `QString` part? It works fine for me: `qDebug() << QString{ "font-size: %1px;" }.arg( 30 );`.

Comment: Yeah, qDebug() shows me the correct output. It's a bit baffling.

Comment: Can't reproduce (Qt5.9, Linux). What happens if you construct the `QString` first as `QString ss = QString("font-size: %1px;").arg(30)` and then do `my_label->setStyleSheet(ss)`?

Comment: G.M. the issue persists.

Comment: If creating the `QString` as an explicit veriable doesn't work then that -- to me at least -- would seem to be completely at odds with the fact that the `qDebug` works.  Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not really sure what the issue is yet. Does it show at default size? if you call my_label->styleSheet() will it return the right string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a combination of two things:

1. I needed to convert the value to a string first
2. The actual value passed to the arg() during runtime had a decimal place, the "30" was just for testing

While I did try different combinations (integer values (30), converting to QString first), I did not try using an integer value AND converting it to QString together.
So everyone was kinda right. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: That's what you get for not posting a test case that reproduces the issue. You'll help yourself greatly by refraining from doing that in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Conver the number to a string, [QString::number](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number):

```
my_label->setStyleSheet(QString("QLabel{font-size: %1 px;}").arg(QString::number(30));
```

Or try it by using [QFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#setPointSize), use this generic function for this purpose:

```
void updateFontSize(QLabel* label, int fontSize) {
    QFont font = label->font();
    if (font.pointSize() != fontSize) {
        font.setPointSize(fontSize);
        label->setFont(font);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @iknownothing Try it with C++ API, i have update the response.

Comment: @MohammedB.B.: Using `QString::number` would be an overhead because there's already an `int` overload of [`QString::arg()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-4) for this.

Comment: @Azeem I'm sure that's not going to be a big problem; the peformance of a function for converting a string to an int really shouldn't be a deciding factor in any program.

Comment: @Clearer: Well, it's a separate function call so it'll have a cost i.e. function call context switching, arguments, stack, etc. and `QString::arg()` is already taking care for it so `QString::number()` simply is redundant.

Comment: @Azeem There is no context switching just because you call a function. If a single function call hurts your program enough that you're worring about it, you've probably got bigger problems.